# Format array for Stripe multiple plan subscription api call

Tags: javascript, arrays, stripe-payments, velo

I'm trying to send multiple plan subscription request to the Stripe API. However I have an array like this

```
0: {"plan":"plan_EaDE7UnYYcicOj","quantity":"2"}
1: {"plan":"plan_EbOzfXj7R9hcdz","quantity":"2"}
```

I want to convert it so that it is in the format that Stripe wants it which is like this

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions \
  -u sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: \
  -d customer=cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a \
  -d items[0][plan]=plan_CBXbz9i7AIOTzr \
  -d items[0][quantity]=2
  -d items[1][plan]=plan_IFuCu48Snc02bc \
  -d items[1][quantity]=2
```

I'm using the fetch method like below

```
const response = await fetch("https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions", {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey
    },
    body: encodeBody(customerId, items) //problem here
  });
```

I have been trying to encode the array into a proper format but everytime I get [Object Object] and the customer id is joined together due to encode.concat

```
    function encodeBody(customerId, items){
      let encoded = "";

      for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(items)) {
      encoded = encoded.concat(k,"=", encodeURI(v), "&");
      }
      encoded = encoded.concat("customer", encodeURI(customerId));
      return encoded;
    }
```

I'm new to using the encoding function so I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your query string's `items` to be in this format:

`items[0][plan]=plan_CBXbz9i7AIOTzr&items[1][plan]=plan_IFuCu48Snc02bc&items[1][quantity]=2`

To do that, you want to iterate over both the `plans` and the properties on each `plan`. You can achieve this with this implementation of `encodeBody()` (uses ES6 since I see you're already using `const` above):

```
function encodeBody(customerId, items) {
  let encoded = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i];

    for (pair of Object.entries(item)) {
      console.log(pair);
      encoded += `items[${i}][${pair[0]}]=${pair[1]}&`;
    }
  }

  encoded += `customer=${customerId}`;

  return encoded;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: Where is this syntax explained? I can't find any reference to it in the docs.